# Preserve height and width dimensions when importing ggplot2 images to Google Slides

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-slides

When I create a file with ggplot2, I can control the image dimensions in `ggsave()`, but when I import the image into Google Slides it consistently gets larger.

For instance if I produce this 4" x 6" image "test.png",

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + 
  theme_minimal() 

ggsave("test.png", height = 4, width = 6)
```

it will import into Google Slides at 4.18" x 6.27", which I can manually change to 4" x 6" in format options, but this is a step I'd rather skip as I tend to update many images many times while iterating on a deck.

Comment: Is this not a resolution issue? Would `ggsave("test.png", height = 4, width = 6, dpi = 72)` solve the problem?

Comment: interesting @teunbrand, that dpi does change the size that the image imports into the deck at. But ultimately I'd prefer to be able to import a high res image without changing the dimensions.